# Windows 8 is not booting up in my sony vaio laptp

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, sony-vaio

Here is my problem:

I have Windows 8 which came preinstalled on my laptop. My laptop is a sony vaio sve15127cnb.

I tried to install kali linux on my laptop as bual boot.

So I restarted my laptop and went into the BIOS, the secure boot option was already disabled. UEFI settings were already selected. I changed my 1st boot device to external drive and restarted the laptop, but the USB was not detected as I was trying to boot from USB.

Then I changed it to legacy mode and restarted, and ran linux as live.

Then I shutdown the laptop and again changed back the mode to UEFI, after that I'm getting

```
GNU GRUB version 2.00-19ubuntu2
grub>
```

At this point, I tried many things but my Windows 8 is not booting. I tried to enable secure boot and restared then it is showing the error "secure boot failed operating system not found".

I tried going back to legacy mode with my USB detached and then get the error "operating system not found".

How can I boot Windows 8? (I will think about installing linux later)

if i install linux in legacy mode, will it help? and also usb is not recognising in uefi mode for boot from usb. but it is recognising in legacy mode. is there a separate software to do so or is it just some other thing?

Comment: You will need a Win 8 disk or USB to run startup repair. This should restore the Win 8 bootloader so Windows can boot normally once again.

Comment: @BigChris i dont have win 8 disk or usb for start up repair. whenever there was a problem with win 8 i used to run refresh windows or reset windows option. do u know any other way how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you will need a Win 8 disk and at least a USB / CD.

To download windows 8 use this [link](http://www.windowsreinstall.com/win8/installs/installfromdownload/index.htm).

This will let you download windows 8 (will require a legal product retail key).

Then to install on CD, you just need to burn the .iso to the disk.

To use a USB (recommended), use [YUMI multiboot](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) .

Comment: as i said i bought the laptop and windows 8 came preinstalled in it. so when 1st time i opened my laptop windows 8 directly opened. so never knew my product key.

Comment: Look underneath laptop, there should be product key 'label' for windows 8.If not, you should be able to contact the supplier of the laptop and obtain the key from them

Comment: That wouldn't be a Retail key, though, would it? It would be an OEM key.

Comment: ya there is no product key. i dont know how to get it now. please help, i really dont know what to do

Comment: or do u know where it is saved on the hard disk bcz i can open live  linux from usb and access the c drive where my windows was installed.

Comment: or do you know what can i do with this grub menu

Comment: @Tetsujin quite often on laptops it also has the windows product key along with the retail key... Anurag just did another google search for you and I found [this](http://www.nthelp.com/Win98_product_key_recovery.htm), please read and let us know if you managed to find a key. If not you'll either have to contact the retailer (where you got laptop from) OR download a cracked version of win8, so you can repair the grub

Comment: Windows 8 pre-installed doesn't come with a product key as it's all contained within the TPM (I think). To be a Windows 8 OEM companies have to ensure their machines comply with Microsoft's security requirements. I believe that includes a TPM and secure boot/UEFI.